# How to send data(String) from HTTP client to server

Tags: python, http, server, client

I've got a simple server, and I need that server to get message from client via http the code of client is

```
import requests
r = requests.post('http://192.168.0.100:7777',data="Hello")
print(r.text)
```

My server doesn't catch anything. But I'm quite sure they are connected since the text from the server is being displayed in the console

Server code

```
int httpCode = http.GET();
if(httpCode>=0){
  String payload = http.getString();
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.println(payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that it's not a server issue? Try printing r.status_code.

Also, generally you'll want to send the data in a json object.

```
import json
import requests
data = json.dumps({'message': 'hello'})
request = requests.post('http://192.168.0.100:7777',data=data)
print(request.status_code)
print(request.text)
```

Comment: Status code is 200
But I'm not 100% sure if it's possible to get data from client by calling GET on server

Comment: Anything from request.text or just None?

Comment: request.text is still Hello World

Comment: Now you can also see the part of server code which should be receiving the message

Comment: Ah, I think I see your problem. Try requests.get instead of requests.post. You also will likely need to modify the server code to accept a post. In python, you're sending a post request, but the server is expected a get.

Comment: Ok so in the python code I'll switch .post wit .get and in the server should I switch .GET with .POST ? If so it doesn't seem to work